# AJAX request happening after turbolinks page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have a ruby on rails 4 application that makes use of turbolinks and jquery ajax requests, and now I'm having some trouble.

The jquery ajax requests work perfectly under normal conditions. I have a remote form containing only a text field which auto-posts as the user types:

```
<%= form_for(section, remote: true) do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_area :title, 'data-behavior' => 'autosubmit', placeholder: "Untitled Section", rows: 1, maxlength: 255 %>
<% end %>
```

If I type a character, the form posts successfully. My problem comes in when it interacts with turbolinks. Here are the steps:

1. Type a character
2. Click a link before the ajax request can complete

   - The linked page is shown as expected
3. Click the browser's back button
4. Type a character
5. Click a link before the ajax request can complete

At this point, it appears that turbolinks has shown me the cached version of the page I clicked on, meaning the URL has changed.

It also appears the ajax request is getting sent AFTER turbolinks changes the page. This is evidenced by the fact that `request.referrer` at this point is the URL of the link I clicked on to interrupt the ajax request instead of the URL of the page the request actually originated from.

So, given all this, I have no idea how to fix this. Perhaps I could get turbolinks to cancel all ajax requests on `page:change`?

Do you have any ideas? Thank in advance!

**EDIT**

Additionally, I'm finding that in the case when the ajax request gets messed up, the `ajax:before` event is not getting fired, though it is getting fired when things appear to work as expected.